# Each prime $p$ not $2$ or $5$ divides $F_{p-1}$ or $F_{p+1}$, where $(F_n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence with $F_1=F_2=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $\{F_n\}$ - Fibonacci sequence: $F_1=F_2=1, F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}, n\ge2$ and $p -$ prime number, $p\not =2, p \not=5$. Prove that $p|F_{p-1}$ or $p|F_{p+1}$

#### My work so far.

I used formula $$F_p^2-1=F_{p-1}\cdot F_{p+1}.$$
But can not solve the problem.

Comment: You can use this paper http://math.stanford.edu/~brianrl/notes/fibonacci.pdf see Theorem 4.3 and Theorem 4.4

Comment: You can show that, for a prime natural number $p\neq 5$, $p$ divides $F_{p+1}$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm 2\pmod{5}$, and $p$ divides $F_{p-1}$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}$.  A proof is here: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h413169p2321819.  Be warned: the OP of that thread did not use the notation $F_n$ for the usual $n$-th Fibonacci number (while $f_n$ in an answer is the conventional $n$-th Fibonacci number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elementary proof inspired by the paper linked by Kelenner:

*Lemme 1*: Let $a\in \mathbb{F}_p, n\geq3 $, if the polynomial $x^2-x-1|x^{n+2}+a\pmod{p}$ then $F_{n+2}\equiv0\pmod{p}$

*Proof:* Calculating mod $p$: we have that $(x^2-x-1)\cdot(F_0x^n+F_1x^{n-1}+...+F_{n-1}x+F_n)=$
$=F_0x^{2n+2}+(F_2-F_1)x^{2n+1}+(F_3-F_2-F_1)x^{2n}+...+$
$+(F_{i+3}-F_{i+2}-F_{i+1})x^{2n-i}+...+(-F_{n}-F_{n+1})x-F_{n+1}=$

$=x^{2n+2}-F_{n+2}x-F_{n+1}$

So if $x^2-x-1|x^{n+2}+a$ then in particular $x^2-x-1$ divide the difference between the polynomials:
$x^2-x-1|(x^{n+2}+a-x^{2n+2}+F_{n+2}x+F_{n+1})$ so

$x^2-x-1|(F_{n+2}x+F_{n+1}+a)$

Since the polynomial on the right is of first degree it must be zero. In particular $F_{n+2}=0$ $\square$

*Lemme 2:* Let $p$ a prime, $p\neq5$, then either $x^2-x-1|x^{p-1}-1\pmod{p}$ either $x^2-x-1|x^{p+1}+1\pmod{p}$

*Proof:*Calculating mod $p$: Let be $\phi,\phi'$ the two roots of $x^2-x-1$ respect $\mathbb{F}_p$. If $p\neq 5$ then $\phi\neq\phi'$ and $\phi\cdot\phi'=-1$ (true in the integer case too). We have that $\phi^p,\phi'^p$ are also roots of $x^2-x-1$  since $\phi^{2p}-\phi^p-1=(\phi^2-\phi-1)^p=0$.

Then evaluating at the $p$-th power otherwise exchanges the two roots otherwise keeps them fixed. In the first case we have $\phi^p=\phi'=\phi$ so $\phi^{p+1}=\phi^{p}\cdot\phi=-1$. Then the roots of $x^2-x-1$ are roots of $x^{p+1}+1$ too so the first polyinomial divide the second one. Otherwise, in tthe second case we have $\phi^{p-1}=1$ so the roots of $x^2-x-1$ are roots of $x^{p-1}-1$ too and we conclude $\square$

Answer (score 3):

There are just two cases to study.
Case **i)**: $5$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$. In such a case $x^2-x-1$ completely splits over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $p$ divides $F_{p-1}$, since
$$ F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right). $$
Case **ii)**: $5$ is not a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$. In such a case $x^2-x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}\simeq \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2-x-1)$. The roots of $x^2-x-1$ can be seen as elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ and by Frobenius' automorphism they are of the form $\alpha,\alpha^p$. By the closed formula
$$ F_{p+1} = \frac{1}{2\alpha-1}\left(\alpha^{p+1}-\alpha^{p^2+p}\right)$$
but since $\alpha^{p^2}=\alpha$, $p$ is a divisor of $F_{p+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_n^m=\binom{n}{m}$.

$p$− prime number, $p≠2,p≠5$.

$$F_{p-1}\cdot F_{p+1}=F_p^2-1$$

$$F_p=\frac{1}{2^{p-1}} \left ( C_{p}^1\cdot 5^0+C_{p}^3\cdot 5^1+C_{p}^{5} \cdot 5^{2}+...+C_p^p \cdot 5^{\left (\frac{p-1}{2}\right )}\right )$$

$p$ - prime number $ \Rightarrow C_p^k\equiv 0\bmod p$ for $k=1,2 . . .(p-1)$

$$2^{p-1}\cdot F_p=5^{\left (\frac{p-1}{2}\right )} \mspace{15mu} \bmod \mspace{15mu} p$$

$$2^{2(p-1)}\cdot F_p^2=F_p^2=5^{p-1}=1 \mspace{15mu} \bmod \mspace{15mu} p$$